# Is it possible to scope an entire javascript file?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope

Say I have a javascript file:

```
function foo(){ alert("I am foo!"); }
```

Now I want to import that javascript, but I want foo to be called from a specific namespace or scope.  For example, a.foo(), b.foo(), etc.

```
function foo(){ alert("I am foo also!"); }

a.foo(); // alerts "I am foo!"
b.foo(); // alerts "I am foo also!"
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit:** Personally I don't think SO users should be responsible for explaining their rationale for having a question, but here it is: I want a user to be able to create a javascript file with certain functions, like show() and hide() and then I use that file and basically do eric.show(), todd.show(), etc. But I don't want Eric and Todd's code to be in the same file and I don't want them to be responsible for writing it in object format.  I'm trying to dumb it down as much as possible for those two.  Brackets confuse them.

Comment: Why not use an object?

Comment: I'd recommend to use CommonJS modules and bundle your files for the browser.

Comment: @Quirliom ... I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to get into calling the file via ajax or maybe using third party modules like before you could always take advantage of the window object and add a new object (your namespace to it) like so:

your html:

```
<html>
    <!-- the stuff you have in your html file -->
    <script src="path/to/file1.js">
    <script src="path/to/file2.js">
</html>
```

file 1:

```
window.namespace = { //or var namespace = {... since window holds all variable scope in modern browsers
    foo:function(){
        alert('I am foo');
    }
};
```

file 2:

```
function foo(){
    alert('I am foo too');
}

//not using $(document).ready() because op didn't mention using jquery
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    //you can directly call anything in window scope in most browsers so
    namespace.foo(); //I am foo
    //or
    window.namespace.foo(); //I am foo
    foo(); //I am foo too
});
```

just remember you have to make sure that both files have had a chance to load before you access them hence the DOMContentLoaded event

also remember any functions or variables declared inside a function are not in the window scope unless explicitly added to window object